# C++ Unable to override base class virtual method

Tags: c++, overriding

I have Base & Derived classs:

```cpp
 class APIHandler : public std::enable_shared_from_this<APIHandler>
 {
   public:

   virtual void on_disconnect( Client::Pointer pClient ) = 0;
   virtual void on_shutdown() = 0;
 }

class EmmiAPIHandler : public FTEAPI::Input::APIHandler
{
  public:
   virtual void on_disconnect( Client::Pointer pClient ) override; ===> Error
   virtual void on_shutdown() override; ========> No error 
}
```

`void on_disconnect()` gives error while `on_shutdown()` doesnt. Error is:

```
 error: 'virtual void Emmi::EmmiAPIHandler::on_disconnect(FTEAPI::Input::APIHandler::Client::Pointer)' marked override, but does not override
     virtual void on_disconnect( Client::Pointer pClient ) override;
```

Method signatures in both base and derived are same here.

Comment: Did you actually implement `on_disconnect()` anywhere for `EmmiAPIHandler`?

Comment: Do you have `Client::Pointer` defined in more than one namespace?

Comment: Also, you do not need to repeat the `virtual` keyword in `EmmiAPIHandler`, you just need to specify `override` and it will imply to the reader that it's a virtual method being overridden.

Comment: And post your full code. If it's too long, then upload it onto GitHub and post a link here.

Comment: @aalimian No, please, no external links. It's the user who must make a simple example, better executable, to post here.

Comment: "*Method signatures in both base and derived are same here*" - clearly they are not *identical* or else you would not be getting the error.  You are likely referring to two separate `Client::Pointer` types.

Comment: It's exactly same paramenters. Another method with same parameter works:
In Base :```
   virtual void disconnect( Client::Pointer pClient ) = 0;
In Derived:
 virtual void disconnect( Client::Pointer pClient ) override; ```

Comment: @scohe001 Yes implemented in .cpp file

Comment: @dxiv I dont see any. In that case other method also shoud fail when override. But only two methods fail to override when other methods with same paramters can add ovverride key.

Comment: @sheikhazad `I dont see any` Then there is something you are not seeing, but the compiler does. Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can at least try to help.

Comment: The fact that you derived from `FTEAPI::Input::APIHandler` instead of simply from `APIHandler` suggests different contexts for the definitions. That lends itself to the possibility that `Client` in one context means something different than in the other. However, that is just speculation without a [mre]. You could start with your current example code and add definitions until the first (and ideally only) compiler error is the "does not override" you ask about. Then see what complications (like namespaces) you can remove while preserving that error message.